# Parsing and Storing HTML Tags Along With Text

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a way to parse unicode strings of html and essentially split all of the elements of the string (html elements as well as individual tokens) and store them in a list. `BeautifulSoup` obviously has some nice functionality for parsing html, such as the `.get_text` method, but this doesn't preserve the tags themselves.

What I need is something like this. Given an html unicode string such as

`s = u'<b>This is some important text!</b>`,

what I would like to have as a result is a list like this:

`['<b>', 'This', 'is', 'some', 'important', 'text!', '</b>']`

There must be an easy way to do this with BeautifulSoup that I'm just not seeing in SO searches. Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** since this has been getting some questions as to the purpose of storing the tags, I'm interested in using the tags as features for a project in text classification. I'm experimenting with using different structural features from an online discussion forum in addition to the n-grams present within forum posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of an odd requirement, so here's an odd but simple solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = u'<b>This is some important text!</b>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

>>> soup.b.prettify().split()
[u'<b>', u'This', u'is', u'some', u'important', u'text!', u'</b>']
```

Comment: Thanks @mhawke, this is really nice. Actually, for generality, if one uses `soup.prettify().split()` this will split on <i>any</i> html tag and make sure it's stored in the list. Thanks for looking at this.